# How to return no value in a string function in C++?

Tags: c++

I have the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>


using namespace std;

int foo() {
    int v1 = rand() % 2;         
    return v1;
}

string get_time() {
    if (foo() == 1) {
        return "";
    }

    return "H: 12 M: 30";
}

int main()
{
 
    while (true) {
        cout << get_time() << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I run this code, and the get_time() function returns "" , there is a new line in the console. I don't want this new line, I only want to print the time without any new lines in the console

Like this:

```
"H: 12 M: 30"
"H: 12 M: 30"
"H: 12 M: 30"
"H: 12 M: 30"
"H: 12 M: 30"
```

Not like this:

```
"H: 12 M: 30"
"H: 12 M: 30"

"H: 12 M: 30"


"H: 12 M: 30"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `<< endl` and change `"H: 12 M: 30"` to `"H: 12 M: 30\n"`

Comment: Yes, this solves the immediate problem. But functions that return strings usually should not be responsible for formatting output; putting a newline at the end of a result string is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @PeteBecker OP asked a specific question and I gave a specific answer. In your opinion my answer is bad. In my opinion the whole concept of returning an empty string and implementing logic into a function called `get_time` is bad. But answers on Stackoverflow shouldn't contain opinions. There are different approaches to solve the problem and therefore there is also a different answer.

Comment: That's what "Yes, this solves the immediate problem." means.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to simply test the value of the string returned by the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>


int foo() {
    int v1 = rand() % 2;         
    return v1;
}

std::string get_time() {
    if (foo() == 1) {
        return "";
    }
    return "H: 12 M: 30";
}

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        auto Time = get_time();
        if (Time != "") {
            std::cout << Time << std::endl;
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```